# PIVOT into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with columns:

```
Anno, Description, Number
________________________
2011    Example1     12
2013    Example2      9
2011    Example4      8
```

......

The value into column `Description` is dynamic

I have to produce a table like:

```
Anno Example1 Example2 Example3 Example4 ........
--------------------------------------------------    
2011   12         0       0        8     ........
2012    0        23      24       36     ........
......
```

I have created a view like this:

```
Declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(Max),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(Max)

Select @cols = STUFF(( Select ','+QUOTENAME(Description)
                       FROM mytable
                       GROUP BY Description
                       Order by Description
                       FOR XML PATH ('',TYPE
                       ).value('.','NVARCHAR(Max)'),1,1,'')

SET @query= 'Select Anno, '+cols+' from
             (Select Anno, Description, Number
              FROM mytable ) as x
              PIVOT
              (
                SUM(Number)
                FOR Description in ('+cols+')
               ) pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

It returns an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: Is the error occurring on the `EXECUTE` line? Assuming it is, when doing dynamic query generation like this, it's often useful to `PRINT` the query before executing it. What does `@query` contain just before it is executed?

Comment: But I wish I had back only a table to display via programming.
Tanks for all

Comment: If you add a `PRINT` statement and then execute it all in Management Studio, you should see the query printed to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of minor syntax errors.  First you are missing a close paren in the `FOR XML PATH`.

```
FOR XML PATH ('',TYPE
```

becomes

```
FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE
```

And second you are storing the column list in a variable and not referencing it as one in your dynamic SQL.  This works correctly.

```
Declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(Max),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(Max)

Select @cols = STUFF(( Select ','+QUOTENAME(Description)
                       FROM mytable
                       GROUP BY Description
                       Order by Description
                       FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE
                       ).value('.','NVARCHAR(Max)'),1,1,'')

SET @query= 'Select Anno, '+@cols+', Total from
             (Select Anno, Description, Number, 
                SUM(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY Anno) AS Total
              FROM mytable ) as x
              PIVOT
              (
                SUM(Number)
                FOR Description in ('+@cols+')
               ) pvt'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bee5/1)**

Comment: +1. Was so close... Got the mistake by comparing **[Query from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042663/dynamic-sql-server-pivot-table)** But you were the first one.

Comment: Tanks it's ok But when you save the View gives me the error:
 incorrect syntax near ' DECLARE

Comment: You can't do declares in a view.  Or multiple queries for that matter.  If you want it to be a view you will have to lay it out completely differently.

Comment: Also,How can I add a column ' Totals ' that is the sum of the dynamic fields??

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @query = '
    SELECT Anno, ' + cols + ' 
    FROM (
        SELECT Anno, Description, Number
        FROM dbo.mytable 
    ) x
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Number) FOR [Description] IN (' + cols + ')
    ) pvt'
FROM (
    SELECT cols = STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + [Description] + ']'
        FROM dbo.mytable d
        GROUP BY [Description]
        ORDER BY [Description]
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
) t

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Also,How can I add a column ' Totals ' that is the sum of the dynamic fields??